# Is this algebra right?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm working with the group of real linear functions ($f(x) = m·x + c, m \neq 0$) with the composition as the group product and via derivative I get that the generators of this group are:

$$\partial_mf = x, \quad \partial_cf = 1\tag1$$

From Eq. (1) we can write the Lie algebra as the set

$$\{r·x + k\ |\ r, k \in \mathbb{R}\}\tag2$$

which is not equal to the group because $r$ can be zero. But is this well done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Under what operation is the set of real linear functions a group?

Comment: Composition, I edit it

Comment: I edit the question because I've realized of some mistakes

Comment: $f$ doesn't seem to be linear...

Comment: This isn't clear.  The set of non-vertical non-horizontal lines in the plane is a group under composition.  I suppose it's also a Lie group, so it has a Lie algebra.  However, why would it be a problem if the Lie algebra is different from the original Lie group?  It should be.

Comment: I'm not having problems because the algebra is different from the group, it's just that I had my doubts due to the similarity between the algebra and the group, and I thought that maybe I was misunderstanding something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Lie algebra as a set of maps to augment the identity map on your realization line is OK, but you should not infer that *x* is somehow significant. *x* is a prop of the realization on a line, and not a group parameter, so it is irrelevant to the generators: it is a placeholder of algebraic position, *(m;c)*. In particular, this set of maps is not practical in specifying the unique Lie bracket of the algebra. See below.

The group is the simplest ever Affine group, in one dimension, a two-parameter nonabelian one; it is represented by upper-triangular 2×2 matrices with 1 in the second row,
$$
 \left( \begin{array}{c} f(x)\\ 1 \end{array}\right)= \left( \begin{array}{cc} m & c\\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right) ~ \left( \begin{array}{c} x\\ 1 \end{array}\right).
$$
Check the composition law $(m;c)\circ (n;d)=(mn;c+md)$.

Around the identity, (1;0), the respective generators are the gradients w.r.t. the parameters m-1,
$$
A=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right) ,
$$
and *c*,
$$
B=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right) 
$$
s.t. $~~~[A,B]=B $, the sparest prototype of a nonabelian Lie algebra.

You may then check that
$$ e^{aA+bB}= \left( \begin{array}{cc} e^a & \tfrac{b}{a}(e^a-1)\\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right) , $$
that is, to say,
$$
a=\ln m, \qquad b=\frac{c \ln m}{m-1}   ~~.
$$

Comment: This is really great. Thank you very much for being so clear and easy to understand.

Comment: Actually, in the 2x2 matrices that represent the group, it is not necessary to have an entry 1 in the second row, second column, right? If we take a zerom we just need to change the vector (f(x), 1) for (f(x), 0) and it will be a good choise too, won't it be?

Comment: Well, a null *m* is not allowed by the definition, as it sends x to a constant *c*...   I assume you want the identity, in the group,  to be easily accessible from your group matrix....

Comment: Ok, I see it. You need that 1 to have the identity [1 0; 0 1] in the group. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. That's it.